# Client Udid is uppercase but the same device in my mac return a lowercase udid, is the same?

Tags: ios, iphone, udid

My client Udid is uppercase but the same device in my mac return a lowercase udid (the characters in udid is the same anyway) , i can create the ad hoc profile adding whic udid? The lower or the uppercase? Or is the same?

Comment: They are the same (and this was asked before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947925/ios-udid-is-upper-case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both UDID are same. When you entered UDID for add device on Apple Developer Account then **it will auto convert in lowercase**.

Comment: Beware, Apple Developer Account doesn't auto convert to lowercase. I wasted a device of my 100 iPhones limit like this. Then had to add another device with lower case.